# Laravel Redirect::route() going to wrong url on vhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, vhosts

I was working on some code today and sent a `Redirect::route()`. Instead of redirecting to the base_url/route as usual, it duplicated the base_url like this:

http://myurl.dev/http://myurl.dev/myroute

I figured I did something wrong, so I went back and tried to isolate the problem. I ended up starting a new project with a new vhost and putting this tiny bit of code in *app/routes.php*:

```php
Route::get(
    'test1',
    [
        'as' => 'test1',
        function () {
            return Redirect::route('test2');
        }
    ]
);

Route::get(
    'test2',
    [
        'as' => 'test2',
        function () {
            return 'test2hello';
        }
    ]
);
```

When I open http://myurl.dev/test1 in a browser, instead of just showing "test2hello" it threw and http not found error because http://myurl.dev/http://myurl.dev/test2 was not found. This only happens on `Redirect::route()`, it works as expected on `Redirect::to()`. It also only happens on vhosts; `Redirect::route()` works as expected if I go to localhost/myurl/public/test1. Any ideas?

---

*UPDATE:*

I was asked for my vhost setup. I am on Mac OSX 10.8.5 and am using the built-in Apache. I've uncommented the *httpd-vhosts.conf* include line in */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*. I've added a few vhosts to */etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*, here's one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/example_blog/public"
    ServerName example_blog.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and the corresponding line in */etc/hosts*:

```
127.0.0.1   example_blog.local
```

and restarted Apache. The folder is named `example_blog.local`.

Comment: How did you set your vhosts? Can you post the configuration? I tested your routes in my laravel installation and I didn't get any problem. I think it is a issue about rewrite mode or vhost is not set correctly in your project.

Comment: @Darwing I've added my vhost setup

Comment: I don't know right now if the directive/tag `Directory` is really important but you are missing it in your vhost configuration. In [this tutorial](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/getting-started) you can see an explanation how to set correctly vhost configuration with Laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem appears to be related to having an underscore in the URL, which does not pass FILTER_VALID_URL:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2511

(no credit to me for the answer as I'm just tidying up this to help others searching for solutions to this)

Comment: Well good people, I regret that I too am experiencing this problem. In my case, the domain name has a dash in it. Also, I'm using a Route group that defines possible subdomains in curly braces. I have a route named 'setup' defined as 'settings/{setup}' Redirect:route('setup', array('error' => '1')) is taking me to:
http://sub.name.our-site.com/http://{subdomain}.{name}.our-site.com/settings/{setup}?error=1
That is literally the URL it tries to load. Shouldn't hyphens be valid in domain names?

Comment: Bless you! I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
Route::get(
    'test1',
    [
        'as' => 'test1',
        function () {
            return Response::make('', 302)->header('Location', route('test2'));
        }
    ]
);

Route::get(
    'test2',
    [
        'as' => 'test2',
        function () {
            return 'test2hello';
        }
    ]
);
```

as you can see we use **Response** Class which **Redirect** itself uses it to send header location :)